# NSPersistentDocument and File menu entries

Tags: swift, core-data

I've created a brand new macOS app using Xcode 9.2, with 'Create Document-based Application' and 'Use Core Data' selected in the project template.

I've made four changes:

1. Edited the CoreData model to add an entity called 'Entity' with two string attributes, 'name' and 'content'.
2. Used "Editor->Create NSManagedObject subclass" to generate convenience methods for the Entity.
3. Replaced the default Window.xib with a new, empty Window.xib.
4. Added the following code to Document.swift, which contains my `NSPersistentDocument` subclass:

   ```
   override func windowControllerDidLoadNib(_ windowController: NSWindowController) 
   {
       super.windowControllerDidLoadNib(windowController)

       let entity = Entity(context: managedObjectContext!)
       entity.name = "TestEntity"
       entity.content = "test content goes here"

       Swift.print("edited: \(self.isDocumentEdited)") // prints "NO"
   }
   ```

I assumed that this would be enough to automatically enable the File->Save... menu item. It is not. It remains grayed out. The value of `isDocumentEdited` as printed is `NO`.

**However**, when I quit the application, I'm asked `Do you want to save the changes made to the document "Untitled"?` in a standard dialog box. So Core Data knows about my changes, but it seems it maybe hasn't connected them with the document window...?

What am I missing here? What do I need to do to associate the foreground document window with an `NSPersistentDocument` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I was missing the following 3 things in my new Document.xib:

1. File's Owner -> Class needed to be set to `Document`
2. I needed to add a Referencing Outlet, to File's Owner, `window` property
3. I needed to add an Outlet from the `delegate` property to File's Owner